# How to take user input and use the if else function to give outputs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to take the user input and use the if else function to base the outcome on it.

This input is a name and if it's a string, the output should be the text `'What a beautiful name you have'` and if it is a int or a float, the output should be `'Sorry , please enter a name'`. But if I enter either an int or a str both outputs are  `'What a beautiful name you have'`. What should I do? Here is my code:

```
name = input("What is your name?")

if type(input) is str:    
    print("What a beautiful name you have!")

elif type(input) is int or float:
    print("Sorry, enter a proper name")
```

Comment: input() always returns a str object, so every time the first condition is invoked.

Comment: Another problem with your code is, you are checking the type of `input`, you should be checking the type of `name` which holds the value

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues.

1) Your using `input` as your `type` argument -> `elif type(input)...`. You should be using `name`.

2) `input()` ALWAYS returns a `str`. You have to type cast it to what you want.

3) `elif type(input) is int or float` doesn't do what you think it does. That is equivalent to `elif (type(input) is int) or float` so it will always be `True` because `float` is Truthy. You need to do `elif type(name) is int or type(name) is float`.

4) You shouldn't use `type(...)` for comparing, instead use `isinstance(name, str)`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
name = input("What is your name?")
if all(x.isalpha() or x.isspace() for x in name):
    print("What a beautiful name you have!")
else:
    print("Sorry, enter a proper name")
```

Note : `name` is always in string format. If you want to check whether there is any number in `name`, then you can do this : `any(i.isnumeric() for i in name)`

Comment: This is probably good enough for most basic uses, [but some assumptions may be wrong](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 1):

The [input function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) returns a string regardless the content of the string. The string `"1"` is a string nonetheless.

What you may want to do is check if the string can be converted into a number without error:

```
s = input("what is your name?")
try:
    float(s)
    print("Sorry, enter a proper name")
except ValueError:
    print("What a beautiful name you have!")
```

Comment: That is alittle going around, trying to check for `float` when you want the input to be a pure string. What about `float("=")`?

Comment: @Tomerikoo Obviously you're right. Was following the logic of the OP regarding to what is a legal name. The real problem of recognizing a name is a bit more complex.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the input from the machine will always be a string. Therefore even if you input a number or a float, it will be considered a string. Consider the following code using regular expressions to identify if your string contains an int/float:

```
import re
name = input("What is your name?")

if re.match('[0-9]', name): 
  print("Sorry enter a proper name")
else:
  print("What a beautiful name")
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This one works partially, but you need to type the name under quotation marks otherwise you will get an error cuz python will be looking for a variable name. If the intgers are written inside the quotation marks they will be seen as str but if not the code will do its job. TBH I don't see a feasible solution without giving the trick away.

```
x = eval(input("What is your name? "))
if isinstance(x, str):
    print ("What a beautiful name you have!")
else:
    print ("Sorry, enter a proper name")
```